# Can’t Import sklearn into Flask App on Google Compute Engine with Apache

Tags: python, flask, scikit-learn, virtual-machine

I can’t import sklearn into the **init**.py file of a flask app I am running on a Google Compute Engine linux (Ubuntu 14.04) VM. The example code below works fine if I remove the import sklearn statement but will not work when that statement is included. The browser waits for a response from the server unit it times out. I can run any other web apps on the system as long as they don’t use sklearn so I know the server works fine.

**init**.py

```
    from flask import Flask
    import sklearn

    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route("/")
    def hello():
        return "Test"

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run()
```

The sklearn library is installed and I can import it and use it without problems in my other python files. Other libraries I need also import fine (numpy, pandas, bs4, ect). The problem is specific to sklearn and to the **init**.py file. It doesn’t actually throw an error if I run the file from the terminal as it would if I tried to import a library that I didn’t have installed. It just doesn’t respond when I try to connect to it through the internet.

There are no other versions of python on the system. It is just the stock python 2.7 version that came with the linux VM.

Comment: How did you install scikit-learn, which version? Can you reproduce the problem locally on your desktop? How do you launch the flask app?

FYI I run your script locally and I cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you cannot document the problem in a way that other people can reproduce it there is very little change anybody will be able to help you.

Comment: I installed scikit-learn 0.17.1 using pip. Numpy and scipy were installed using apt-get. I can't reproduce the problem locally. The app works just fine locally. In terms of launching the app, I went through this process (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps) and replaced the __init__.py file with the code I provided in this question. All other apps that don't include the sklearn import work fine on the Linux VM. I didn't realize that the VM comes with both Python 2.7 and 3.4. Sklearn is installed on and I'm using 2.7.

Comment: So you are trying to launch flask from apache. You should try to run it locally with apache and look into the apache log files for error messages.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I was experiencing was the result of apache not working well the C dependencies in sklearn. More information can be found here (https://github.com/naturalis/nbclassify/issues/2).

The solution:

Add this line

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

below this line

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
```

in the Virtual Host config file (step 4 in this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps).

The app now works with no issues.